# Ireport Using Oracle Function

Tags: ireport

I have a oracle function(SOS_NUMBER_TO_WORD_JR_F).it has INTEGER parameter and return type is STRING.  Now i want call this function from Ireport variable or text field. I did not kwnow how to do it? Any one help my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you call it in your query?

```
 SELECT SOS_NUMBER_TO_WORD_JR_F($P{the_integer_parameter}) AS RETURNS_A_WORD
 FROM MY_TABLE
```

If that doesn't work, provide us with a little more information about how you normally call the function.

Comment: s i called it but it returns null values

Comment: s.it returns amount in words

Comment: In your report, can you add a field for $P{the_integer_parameter} to verify what you're passing into the report? Enter an integer and tell us the value of $P{the_integer_parameter} in your report.